# Python Click command names

Tags: python, python-click

I'm using the click package for creating a command line tool. However, I would like to have a 'list' command. For example:

```
@click.command
@click.option(help='list...')
def list():
    # do stuff here
```

Is there another way in click to pass in a command name other than having it as the function name? I don't want this function to shadow python's built in `list`. I've looked through the documentation and can't really find anything about command names -- I've read up on command aliases but that doesn't seem to help this problem. Or do I not need to worry about `list` being shadowed since it's being wrapped by the click decorator? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You can provide the `name` argument when you use the `command` decorator. Once you've done that, you can name your function whatever you want:

```
@click.command(name='list')
def list_command():
    pass
```

See the [Click documentation](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/5.x/api/#decorators) for details.